# How to change row value into column header

Tags: sql, teradata

```
select
extract(year from datetimestamp ) Yr,extract(month from datetimestamp) Mn,
c.weekday_of_month wk, a.aircraft_type,count( a.aircraft_type)  from fcm_bv.Flights b
join fcm_bv.Fleet a on  b.aircraftid=a.tail 
 join SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR c
 on cast(b.datetimestamp AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') = cast(c.calendar_date AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
where cast(datetimestamp as date) >= '2011-09-01'
and cast(datetimestamp as date) <= '2011-09-30'  order by wk
group by Yr,Mn,wk,a.fleet,a.aircraft_type
```

While Running above Query I am getting out put like this

```
Yr      Mn  wk  AIRCRAFT_TYPE   Count(AIRCRAFT_TYPE)
2011    9   1   B737-700        1744
2011    9   1   B737-800        131
2011    9   1   B737-800W       2711
2011    9   1   B737-8BK        180
2011    9   1   B737-700W       329
```

But I need output in below format

```
Yr   Mn    wk    B737-700    B737-800  B737-800W   B737-8BK    B737-700W      
2011 9      1      1744       131          2711        180         329
```

Could any one help me

Answer (score 0):

In the past when I have needed to do this the pivot was against a discrete, managable volume of categories and the following SQL has served me well:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b.datetimestamp) AS Yr
     , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM b.datetimestamp) AS Mn
     , C.weekday_of_month
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN a.aircraft_type = 'B737-700' THEN a.aircraft_type ELSE NULL END) AS B737-700
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN a.aircraft_type = 'B737-800' THEN a.aircraft_type ELSE NULL END) AS B737-800
     , /* Other Known Aircrafts */
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN a.aircrat_type NOT IN ('<list of known aircraft types>') THEN a.aircraft_type ELSE NULL END) AS Uncategorized_Aircraft
FROM fcm_bv.Flights b
join fcm_bv.Fleet a on  b.aircraftid=a.tail 
 join SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR c
 on cast(b.datetimestamp AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') = cast(c.calendar_date AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
WHERE cast(datetimestamp as date) >= '2011-09-01'
  AND cast(datetimestamp as date) <= '2011-09-30'  order by wk
GROUP BY Yr,Mn,wk,a.fleet
```

If you have to pivot against a constantly changing category it may be best to leave the pivoting to MS Excel or BI tool of choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Relay thanks a lot for your reply ..but i have tried  that one while executing that query i am getting below out put......................Yr Mn wk  B737-700  B737-800  B737-700W  B737-800W  B737-8BK Count(AIRCRAFT_TYPE)
2011 9 1 1744 0 0 0 0 1744
2011 9 1 0 131 0 0 0 131
2011 9 1 0 0 0 2711 0 2711
2011 9 1 0 0 0 0 180 180
2011 9 1 0 0 329 0 0 329 but i need output which i have mention with question... how i can do this with the help of pivot table ...thanks rahul